# How to use setAttribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is this the correct format?

```
var title = new_element.setAttribute('jcarouselindex', "'items+1'");
alert(title);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to put the second parameter in quotes.

```
var title = new_element.setAttribute('jcarouselindex', items+1);
```

If you want to set a custom attribute then you can use **[HTML5 data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)**, something like

```
var title = new_element.setAttribute('data-jcarouselindex', items+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is syntactically correct JS/DOM, but there is no 'jcarouselindex' attribute in HTML and using `setAttribute` (as opposed to setting properties that map to attributes) is generally bad practice as it is buggy in MSIE (although not in such a way that will cause a problem in this case).

You might not be intending to have `<foo jcarouselindex="&#39;items+1&#39;">` as your end result though.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery?

var title = $('#new_element').attr('jcarouselindex', "'items+1'");
alert(title);

Comment: You're showing how to set the attribute, but also get it. jQuery is good to get over cross-browser compatibility issues, but if you're already using it, you might as well use `.data`.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many quotes:

```
var index = items + 1;
new_element.setAttribute('jcarouselindex', index);
```

Remark: there's no `jcarouselindex` attribute defined in HTML elements so this is not very clean code.